# Query to read soup data for custom object in Android app

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am looking for some examples for Android app of how can I write a query to retrieve data from a custom object soup that I created. Is it diferent than standard object soup structure

Can anyone give some sample code/ examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The querying process is the same for standard objects and custom objects. For example, if you do this for opportunity

```
return query("SELECT {Opportunity:Name}, {Opportunity:Id}, {Opportunity:AccountId}, {Opportunity:OwnerId}, {Opportunity:Amount} FROM {Opportunity}");
```

Similarly for a custom object, you would do something like

```
return query("SELECT {MyObj:Name}, {MyObj:Id}, {MyObj:Field1}, {MyObj:Field2} FROM {MyObj}");
```

That should work.